# Google Distance Matrix API no output

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use Distance Matrix API to calculate the distance between 2 places.
Because this is the first time I'm trying to use this API I litterally copied the code I found on the [Google Documentation's page](http://bit.ly/RCwQ7z)  and pasted on my page.
But, I can't see any kind of output and I don't know why.
This is [my page](http://www.angtrim.com/test/vediamo.html)

And this is the source :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">

<!-- Google Api -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDDMkiaVfr1y0QCsx_qUsJKIBAWpkyXZrY&sensor=false">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(55.930385, -3.118425);
var origin2 = "Greenwich, England";
var destinationA = "Stockholm, Sweden";
var destinationB = new google.maps.LatLng(50.087692, 14.421150);

var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
service.getDistanceMatrix(
  {
    origins: [origin1, origin2],
    destinations: [destinationA, destinationB],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, callback);

function callback(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) 
  {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
    document.writeln(response.originAddresses[1]);    
  }

  else {
    document.writeln("error");

       }
  }  

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have no idea why that doesn't work. First, I recommend you use **jQuery**. You can find it [here.](http://jquery.com/)

First, wrap your code in a `$(document).ready()` function, so that it is executed *when the page is ready*,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Everything in your original script block
  var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(55.930385, -3.118425);
  // etc etc      
});
```

Secondly, it's alot easier writing to the document when you know **where** you're writing to. Make a `div` that will hold your location data.

```
<body>
<div id="location"/>
</body>
```

Thirdly, when you have your location from Google, change the text in your `div` to match:

```
$("#location").text(response.originAddresses[1]);
```

Dealing with the document without jQuery is a nightmare, I highly recommend using this library.

Comment: So how can I solve this displaying problem?
Where is the error?

Comment: Do me a favour and try wrapping your `<script>` that does the processing like this `<body><pre><script>` **javascript here** `</script></pre></body>`. Perhaps you're not writing the data to the body?

Comment: Done, but the result is the same: no output.

Comment: For anyone else landing to this question in 2019, you might also want to check that you have enabled the Distance Matrix API on your console.cloud.google.com . Welcome.